# Medical (anatomy) issue

Tags: medical

I’m not a native speaker, but I found a difference in my anatomy book between “**is related medially**” and “ **is located medially**” that they have the opposite meaning...

Is it true?

Comment: Can you give more context for the use of the phrase "related medially"? At least the complete sentence where it is used.

Comment: Located medially is a relative term meaning you will find A closer to the center line of the body than B. Related does not mean further away, but could make sense if we hear more. Distal is the anatomical term for further away from the center line.

Comment: Notice that this is medical terminology, and the answer should reference a medical dictionary.